# How can update localforage in AngularJs when backend data is changed

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am working on AngularJs $localforage and able to fetch or set the localstorage, but how should I maintain the consistency of data between database and localstorage?

How can I come to know that the backend data has changed and removed the previous localstorage data and update or load the new data.

Comment: How about `socket.io` ?

Comment: Sockets, polling the server are your options.

Comment: @ Rayon @ Tarun can you please elaborate little more

Answer (score 0):

How do you interact with the backend? Perhaps with **REST api** (perhaps `$http` or `$resource` service, or something third-party)? In this case, you cannot know if something has changed.

What are you looking for is called a "**realtime**" system.
The best way to built it's to use sockets.

Please take a look at the [socket.io](http://socket.io/) or [faye](https://github.com/faye/faye), or [deepstream](https://deepstream.io/), or whatever.

But keep in mind, in some enterprise networks sockets can be blocked and not all old browsers support it (there still few old technologies for this case, but i'm not an expert in it)

For learning purpose try to google something like "*how to create a chat with sockets*" (example with [socket.io](http://socket.io/get-started/chat/)).

Comment: Thanks Sergey Panfilov,

I am using $http

Comment: Yep, it's ok, but keep in mind, that angular's developer suggest to use `$resource` instead of `$http` for interaction with `REST` (especially with `RESTful`). And I suggest so, but it's a bit complicated for understanding

Comment: @SergeyPanfilov If I am not wrong $resource is using $http under the hood, so this choice can be just a matter of style right?

Comment: @ Vignesh you are correct, but I have to change $http to socket.io if I needed the realtime data changes in Angular.

Comment: @Vignesh Yes, It's more about `REST` concept. When you use $resource, you will be able to work with entities from backend in a way like `User.$get()`, `User.$save()`, instead of writing own functions or call the $http foe each request.

Comment: yeah, I get it now thanks. But I guess the webservice must be RESTFUL in order to use $resource. Thanks.